# Find column means of an unsorted 2D array based on last column in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wish to find the means of each of the columns (except last column) of a 2D NumPy array.  The last column has a classifier/identifier.  So **without sorting the array** based on the classifier, I wish to find the mean of each column based only on each classifier. What follows are example rows of the 2D matrix.

```
row1 = [1, 2, 3,...,0]
row2 = [2, 3, 4,...,1]
row3 = [3, 4, 5,...,0]
row4 = [4, 5, 6,...,1]
...
rowN = [9, 8, 7,...,0]
```

Based on the rows above, I want the means of each column of the 2D array for only rows that have classifier = 0 and then classifier = 1.  Is there a pythonic way to do this without if statements and without first sorting the array?

Comment: Are you using NumPy?

Comment: Yes. I am using NumPy.  However, I can also use generic Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the rows on the classifier values you want and perform the mean of all columns but the last one:

```
a   = # your matrix

classifier0 = a[:,-1]==0
mc0 = np.mean(a[classifier0,:-1],axis=0) 

classifier1 = a[:,-1]==1
mc1 = np.mean(a[classifier1,:-1],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to doing this without using `if` or sorting is to use the key as an index, whether to an array or a `dict` as I use below.

Using NumPy, this is pretty easy using [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) and [`mean`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

```
import numpy as np

def sum_by_col(array, keycol):
    key_arr = array[:, keycol]
    array = np.delete(array, keycol, axis=1)
    means = {}
    for key in np.unique(keys):
        means[key] = array[key_arr == key].mean(axis=0)
    return means
```

If you want to do it without NumPy, you might end up with two top-level loops. First, you could go through and group the elements by key (either as matrices or running sums), then you could go through again to compute the means.

Comment: Thanks Mok!  I didn't know that Boolean indexing of arrays was even a possibility.  I did some reading on the documentation and I can think of a ton of problems where that would have worked for me.  Another tool in the toolbox.

Comment: There's a lot of cool stuff you can do with NumPy's indexing capabilities and the relevant methods. Also note that in recent NumPy versions, some functions, like [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) can take a boolean array as the `where` argument, telling it which elements to operate on. (And if you like my answer, please accept it.)

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood your question:
Let's imagine this is your 2D numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
A =np.array([[1, 2, 3,0],[2, 3, 4,1], [3, 4, 5,0],[4, 5, 6,1]])
```

This is the way to get the mean of each column based on the value of the classifier (last column in your matrix).

```
print('1-Classifier mean:',A[A[:,-1]==1].mean(axis=0)[:-1])
print('0-Classifier mean:',A[A[:,-1]==0].mean(axis=0)[:-1])
```

Result:

```
1-Classifier mean: [3. 4. 5.]
0-Classifier mean: [2. 3. 4.]
```